# What are the tradeoffs associated with using the `via-ir` build flag?

Tags: solidity, evm, solidity-0.8.x, yul

I am working on a project where the `via-ir` build flag has been tremendously useful. However, I haven't been able to find the tradeoffs associated with using the flag beyond [minor semantic changes](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/ir-breaking-changes.html#semantic-only-changes) that shouldn't affect my contracts in any way. I have found the building contracts is significantly slower as well, but that's about it so far.

To summarize (the tradeoffs I'm aware of so far):

- small semantic differences
- longer build times
- slightly less gas efficient (through my own off-chain experimentation)

Answer (score 0):

Contracts built using the `--via-ir` are also simpler and easier to follow because of less scoping and workarounds are necessary.